# Formula typed in quill.js not rendering correctly in html

Tags: javascript, html, quill, katex

I am typing math formulae in Quill.js (uses KaTeX) and rendering it as an html. However the formula seems to be rendering twice.[image]

When I inspected the HTML, there are two span elements corresponding to each part. The correct one has class "katex-mathml" and another has the class "katex-html" with attribute "aria-hidden" set to true and still is visible on the page. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the default behavior of Katex. From https://katex.org/docs/options.html:

```
output: string. Determines the markup language of the output. The valid choices are:

html: Outputs KaTeX in HTML only.
mathml: Outputs KaTeX in MathML only.
htmlAndMathml: Outputs HTML for visual rendering and includes MathML for accessibility. This is the default.
```

Are you perhaps just missing to include the katex css?

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.13.16/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-6LkG2wmY8FK9E0vU9OOr8UvLwsaqUg9SETfpq4uTCN1agNe8HRdE9ABlk+fVx6gZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Otherwise your options are:

- specify the katex option to only produce html or mathml (not both), or
- manually add a css rule `katex-html { display: none; }` (or analogously for mathml).